# Google Apps Mail + Nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, godaddy

One client bought a domain with GoDaddy and the nameservers were changed to others and their email was configured on our server.

Now, those new nameservers are not working and the client wants to be able to send and receive emails. Since yesterday the server is down, and I was thinking in using Google Apps service.

Would it work if I change the MX Records for those that [Google provides](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33353) on GoDaddy DNS Manager but mantaining the nameservers that are not working? I know they will have to pay.

I'm not supposed to see this things but I would like to know if it's possible. Or is it possible to configure it on Amazon Route53?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit the DNS with Go Daddy you will first have to change the nameservers back to Go Daddy's nameservers.

Log in to your Account Manager.
1. Next to Domains, click Launch.

2. Select the domain name(s) you want to modify.
3. From (Nameservers), select Set Nameservers.
4. Select: I want to park my domains — This option parks your domain name on our parked servers. When someone opens your domain name from a Web browser, our default parking page displays.
5. (Optional) If DNSSEC is available for the domain name's extension and the domain name is hosted with another provider, you can click Manage DS Records to set up self-managed DNSSEC. See About Self-Managed DNSSEC for information.
6. Click OK.

Once you have default Go Daddy nameservers you can edit the DNS records needed for Google Apps.

To Access the Zone File Editor
1. Log in to your Account Manager.

2. Next to Domains, click Launch.
3. Click the domain name you want to update, and, in the DNS Manager section, click Launch.

Comment: But what if the owner of the domain have changed? And now the GoDaddy account which manage the domain doesn't have the DNS Premium thing and the costumer doesn't want to pay. So I guess it's not possible, and now the people who see the server have bought another one and now it's solved. But thank you for the information, I have done it with my own account and it worked!